# Rails has_many :though STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets start with code that may go like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_many :submitted_photos
  has_many :posted_photos

  has_many :handshakes, through: :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class PostedPhoto < Photo
  has_many :handshakes, inverse_of: :poster, foreign_key: 'poster_id'
end

class SubmittedPhoto < Photo
  has_many :handshakes, inverse_of: :submitter, foreign_key: 'submitter_id'
end

class Handshake < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submitter, class_name: 'SubmittedPhoto'
  belongs_to :poster,    class_name: 'PostedPhoto'
end
```

The STI part and associations between photos and handshakes work fine. The problem is getting all user's handshakes through his photos.

Using the code above Rails will obviously complain that model `Photo` does not have an association called `handshakes`. Is there any facility in AR that would allow me to specify a relation of this kind? If not, what query would you write to get them?

Comment: Why can't you add has_many :handshakes to the photo model?

Comment: Can you confirm, you ultimately want to get all the photos this user has either posted **or** submitted (which is through the `Handshake` class)? Is that correct?

Comment: I want to get all the handshakes where any of user's photos (submitted or posted) if either poster or submitter of the handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code, looked like an easiest option to solve this problem.

```
class User
  def handshakes
    Handshake.where('submitter_id IN (?) OR poster_id IN (?)', submitted_photo_ids, posted_photo_ids)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use in `User`:

```
has_many :submitted_handshakes, through: :submitted_photos, source: :handshakes
has_many :posted_handshakes, through: :posted_photos, source: :handshakes
```

I understand this works as is you had:

```
user.submitted_handshakes ----> user.submitted_photos.handshakes
```

Obviously handshakes method does not exist in submitted_photos, but AR made this for you by joining tables.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but I don't need this level of granularity. What I'm looking for is basically a merge of those two, on database/AR level.

Comment: a merge of those two is to have `has_many :handshakes` and it returns all `handshakes` because you have not scoped `photos`. do you want to avoid scoping `photos` in user?

Comment: if I write `user.handshakes` you want to return `posted_handshakes` or  `submitted_handshakes`?

Comment: Please, see my comment under the question in response to @Teeg. Answer to your question is basically both.

Comment: hmm, I think you already have what you want: `The problem is getting all user's handshakes through his photos.`  and in your comment `I want to get all the handshakes where any of user's photos if either poster or submitter of the handshake.`

Comment: Yes, but this solution is two separate methods and two separate queries. Surely I can do something like `handshakes = user.posted_handshakes + user.submitted_handshakes` to get all the handshakes, but I'd rather prefer to do it on a database level if possible. But maybe it's easier to do it like this.

Comment: hmmm, `user.handshakes == user.posted_handshakes + user.submitted_handshakes ` ? I thought yes, from you have written, and it is doing it in DB level, could you print generated SQL for `user.handshakes`?

Comment: This way the results are merged as Ruby arrays and therefore it does two queries. Merging them raises error. https://gist.github.com/mikekreeki/ec2125ce25b76518a07a

Comment: The reason why I'm looking database solution is that I want to be able to query them more, e.g. `user.handshakes.where(state: 'foo')`.

Comment: you can do `user.handshakes.where...` with the first form you showed: `User has_many :handshakes, through: :photos`

Comment: I can't. With `User has_many :handshakes, through: :photos` Rails will rails error saying there's no relationship called `handshakes` on `Photo` model. And I can't define it on Photo, because it's definition is different for PostedPhoto and SubmittedPhoto.

Comment: I come up with another solution which seems to be most efficient way to do it, check my other answer.