# How to join two 'has_many_through' associations into another association?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to create an additional association that combines two other associations.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cats
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :pets(dogs and cats)  ???
end
```

Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

I need to pull records out of a join table regardless of what column they are in.  **This is purely an optimization question** so that I don't need to ping the db twice for each association.

**Edit:**

I've chosen a poor set of data examples.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :senders (is a person object) 
  has_many :receivers (is a person object)
  has_many :contacts(friends and enemies)  ???
end
```

There is a join table called faxes that has fields friend_id and enemy_id

I want the rails way to say:

```
SELECT DISTINCT persons.* 
  FROM persons 
  WHERE persons.id IN 
  ( 
    SELECT faxes.sender_id 
      WHERE fakes.receiver_id = (?)
  )     
  OR  persons.id IN 
  ( 
    SELECT faxes.receiver_id 
      WHERE fakes.sender_id = (?)
  )
```

Comment: What do you mean by ping the db twice? Do you mean as in multiple select statements? If so, the only way to retrieve both cats and dogs with a single select is if they are stored in the same table using STI.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of class inheritance.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end

class Pets < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Dog < Pet
end

class Cat < Pet
end
```

Something similar to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245705/rails-has-many-though-sti)

Comment: I need to pull records out of a join table regardless of what column they are in.  This is purely an optimization question so that I don't need to ping the db twice for each association.